# Fabrikam/Contoso example VM

Tags: windows, active-directory

We are an Silver Partner (Portals and Collaboration) ISV and need a test domain to test our product. I know a lot of companies spend a while setting up a fleet of VM's to test on, but is there a VM out there from Microsoft with an example AD Domain set up on it?

There appears to be examples of Fabrikam and Contoso servers but I don't know where to look.

Comment: I would have thought that this was an unanswerable question, but @uSlackr has provided a very interesting and potentially useful lead. Be sure to check into the licensing implications of using such images in a test environment: you almost certainly need an MSDN subscription. Also, will your company need to support older versions of Windows Server? What about 32-bit versions? If your new product is the sort of thing that will be an *investment* for your clients, the right thing to do is to *require* Server 2008 R2 or newer and refrain from getting bogged down in supporting legacy platforms.

Comment: Thanks Miles - we are only supporting 2008 R2 with this product. Older products are in the process of going through a change to require 2008 R2 also. We have MSDN and are a Silver Partner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this VM download from Microsoft for AD, Sharepoint, etc.  It's probable overkill but its a start.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27417